# Is it possible to take the reciprocal of a vector?

Tags: vectors

My question is quite simple but I have not been able to find a satisfying answer to it.

Say I have a column vecotr $v$ with $3$ numbers in it: $5$, $6$ and $7$.

How would I symbolically represent changing that vector into a column vector that contains $\frac{1}{5}$, $\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{7}$ aka the reciprocals of all its elements?

$1/v$ seems to be invalid based on what I have found this far.
Is there any convenient way to represent this?

Comment: There is no reciprocal of a vector, you cannot divide by a vector.

Comment: As Ryan Reynold's character in Harold and Kumar Go to White Castle asked "...but why???"

Comment: Division by a vector is not a defined operation, but you may define it like this for your use.

Comment: Simply say "Let $\mathrm u$ be a vector with components $u^i=1/v^i$"

Comment: You can write it in vector form as $$\left[ \begin{matrix}\frac{1}{v\cdot i} \\ \frac{1}{v\cdot j} \\ \frac{1}{v\cdot k} \end{matrix}\right ] $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reciprocal of a vector is not a well-defined operation. But you can introduce some special notation, so you can communicate to others by explaining the notation. For instance, let $v$ be your column vector:
$$v = \begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
6 \\
7 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You may choose the notation $1/v$ to mean:
$$\frac{1}{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{5} \\
\frac{1}{6} \\
\frac{1}{7}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You could also use other notations, say $v_{rec}$ (from reciprocal) or $v^{-1}$. In summary, it is always a matter of (a) defining a notation and making it clear to the reader what it does mean and (b) make it self-consistent so that the same notation is not used to represent different objects.

Answer (score 0):

The operation that you are referring to *is* an inverse operation -- relative to [Hadamard products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). The notation $\circ$ is often used for this product, so a natural (and not unprecedented -- the Wikipedia article linked to above uses it) notation for the operation is $v^{\circ-1}$.

This is probably the closest that you will come to standard notation for the operation. Whether or not you want to use it might depend on whether or not the perspective of Hadamard products sheds any light on what you are using the operation for.